# How to resize a cross domain iframe when content changes?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I would like to embed a blog into my website and, as i see, the most user friendly way is coustomizing a tumblr blog and embeding it via an iFrame. The only proble is this: During the coustomizing procces i added a read more button to my blog, so it is not necessary to scroll trought the full lenght of every post, but now when a user clicks te "read more" button the content "overflows" the boundaries of the iFrame and I can't seem to find a way to constantly update the hieght according to the content inside. I don't know Js very well, but I found two scripts:

**Option 1:**
*The iFrame hosting page:*

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            // Create IE + others compatible event handler 
            var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent"; 
            var eventer = window[eventMethod]; 
            var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message"; 

            // Listen to message from child window 
            eventer(messageEvent, function (e) { 
              document.getElementById('content').style.height = e.data + 'px'; 
            }, false); 
</script>
```

**Option 1:**
*The Tumblr page:*

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function postHeightMessage() { 
      var actual_height = document.getElementById('content').scrollHeight; 
      parent.postMessage(actual_height + 50, "*"); 
    } 

    function adjust_iframe_height() { 
      // Reset iframe height (for Chrome and Safari) 
      var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent); 
      var isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent); 
      if (isChrome || isSafari) { 
        parent.postMessage(200, "*"); 
      } 

      // Send actual iframe height 
      setTimeout(postHeightMessage, 100); 
    } 
</script>
```

**Option 2:**
I used [this](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) script library from "davidjbradshaw". I copied this code from the example file ("I don't know Js very well..."):
*The iFrame hosting page:*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/site/iframe-resizer-master/js/iframeResizer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            iFrameResize({
                log                     : true,                  // Enable console logging
                enablePublicMethods     : true,                  // Enable methods within iframe hosted page
                resizedCallback         : function(messageData){ // Callback fn when resize is received
                    $('p#callback').html(
                        '<b>Frame ID:</b> '    + messageData.iframe.id +
                        ' <b>Height:</b> '     + messageData.height +
                        ' <b>Width:</b> '      + messageData.width + 
                        ' <b>Event type:</b> ' + messageData.type
                    );
                },
                messageCallback         : function(messageData){ // Callback fn when message is received
                    $('p#callback').html(
                        '<b>Frame ID:</b> '    + messageData.iframe.id +
                        ' <b>Message:</b> '    + messageData.message
                    );
                    alert(messageData.message);
                },
                closedCallback         : function(id){ // Callback fn when iFrame is closed
                    $('p#callback').html(
                        '<b>IFrame (</b>'    + id +
                        '<b>) removed from page.</b>'
                    );
                }
            });


</script>
```

*The Tumblr page:*

```
<script src="../js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://fiktiv.dyndns.org/site/iframe-resizer-master/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div style="clear: both; display: block;"></div>
```

The first option works fine until i click the read more button...
The second option, if i know correctly, has the ability to update the height of the iFrame if the content's height changes so i tryed to use that, but it does not work with the tumblr blog... It works with the other pages but if i try to load the "Cikkek" page, the iFrame is just not resizing it stays the same height as the page that was loaded in it before the blog.

So i am asking you to help me solve this resizing problem, I realy appreciate any help and thank you for your time.

The webpage: http://fiktiv.dyndns.org/site/
*(If it is not available please forgive me! I am hosting this on my laptop until it's not completely ready, but i'll do my best to make it available in the next couple of days.)*

Kovács Levente

Comment: The Tumblr blog: http://fiktivcikkek.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, not the ultimate, but the "good enough for me" answer:
I made a "cikkek.php" on the server and called the tumblr blog with include and now it works fine with ***option 2***(, however the buttons at the bottom right of the posts don't work, it resizes if i click the "read more" button).

```
<?php
    include 'http://fiktivcikkek.tumblr.com/';
?>
```